# How to use same DAOs inside and outside of a (OpenEntityManagerInView) web environment?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Our application consists of three parts:
 1. A **core** module, which contains model and DAO classes and the spring configuration.
 2. A **web** module, which uses the core package and is executed in a (portal) web environment.
 3. A **tasks** module, which also uses the core package and is executed as a scheduled task (no web context)

We try to introduce the OpenEntityManagerInView pattern with the [Spring Filter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.html) for the web module. As far as I understand it, the DAOs must not close the EntityManager because the filter does it. Furthermore, I would inject an `EntityManager` with `@PersistenceContext` instead of `EntityManagerFactory` with `@PersistenceUnit` (is that right?).

But how can I reuse the same core package with these modifications in the *tasks* module? There is no Filter which controles the lifecycle of the EntityManager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` is usually used to complement [Spring transaction management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html), as follows:

- You define transaction boundaries in your code. Inside a transaction you can use `EntityManager` injected with `@PersistenceContext` (or Hibernate session obtained from `getCurrentSession()`). Also transactions define JPA [Units of Work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html), i.e. all changes to persistent object you made inside a transaction will be propageted to the database automatically.
- But sometimes you need to access the database outside of defined transaction (the most notable case is lazy loading when rendering a view). For this case you have `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` that allows you to access the database and use `@PersistenceContext` at any point during HTTP request processing.

As you can see, `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` acts as a substitute for absent transaction, therefore you can run the same code without `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` if you do it inside a scope of transaction. So, you need to define transactons appropriately to make sure that all persistence-related code in your *tasks* module runs inside a transaction.

Comment: Thank you, this is a clear explantation. Will `@PersinstenceContext` give me a fresh, threadsafe EntityManager for every request altough my DAO is a singleton?